# System("cls") inside while (1) loop causes stalling before execution

Tags: c, windows, while-loop

This problem was experienced in a larger project but I distilled it down to this example to show what is happening.
In the code below, I want/expect it to print the word 'hello', pause for a bit, and then start flashing the word 'goodbye'.
When I execute the code, though, it stalls for around 7 seconds, during which I cannot close out of the program. Once that time is up, if I clicked the 'x' to close out, it will do so; otherwise it will finally do the behavior I expected (show 'hello', wait for a bit, and start flashing 'goodbye').

I have executed it in both CodeBlocks and from the Command Prompt, and it behaves the same.
I've also tried to look for the answer to this, but I wasn't able to find anything.
Can you please suggest an explanation for what is going on, if you know?

Thank you

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main() {
printf("hello");
Sleep(500);
while (1){
    system("cls");
    printf("goodbye");
}
  return 0;
}
```

Update:

I have (somewhat) figured out what is going on.
I found that if I 'Build' the project in Codeblocks, and then run it, the first 2 runs have the stall. After those runs, it does not stall anymore in future runs.

I don't know why that is, but that is what is happening.

Comment: It is doing a lot of IO operations in a tight loop. I would expect it to "stall".

Comment: Buffering issue from lack of line feed?

Comment: Just to more explicitly explain the previous comment - stdout is line buffered by default. So it may not output to terminal without a newline in the string or until it reaches some buffer limit. That could be why you see nothing for a few seconds and why the terminal stalls - it is in a CPU tight loop until the stdout buffer fills up at which point it starts outputting to terminal. Try adding `fflush(stdout)` after the `printf`.

Comment: You also need a call to `Sleep` (or maybe two) in that `while` loop.

Comment: Can't reproduce. The message flickers at a varying rate, and it responds to Ctrl-C.

Comment: Using "cls" in an external process is silly when you can use the console API yourself to clear the screen.

Comment: Note that the `system()` call is synchronous. Mine managed about 60 calls / second.

Comment: Someone above said they cannot reproduce it. Can anyone get the same behavior as I described?

Answer (score 0):

To get a blinking effect, you probably want to move the sleep function inside your
"while" loop and have a call to the sleep function for both the printing and the clearing.  For example, here is a snippet of code expanding upon your sample a bit.

```
int main() {
printf("hello\n");

    while (1){
        sleep(1000);
        system("clear"); /* On a Windows platform, this would be "cls" */
        sleep(1000);
        printf("goodbye\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Having a sleep function call on either side of the "printf" function provided a blinking effect.  FYI, I built this on my Linux machine, where the sleep function takes an integer value for seconds.  So, in my example, I have a one second pause.  You might have to adjust the value a bit for Windows.

Regards.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I changed your code to make it work for windows and I ran it. It still stalled for around 3 seconds before it displayed anything.
I am wondering if I am the only one who is experiencing this problem somehow.

I also added newline characters and Sleep to my original code, and while it cut down the stall time from ~7 seconds to ~3 seconds, it still persists.

Comment: You might swap the "printf()" and "system("cls")" statements around as noted in my revised answer.  Also, I see that the "Sleep" function in windows expects a value for milliseconds instead of seconds, so maybe try a value of 1000 milliseconds.  See if that gives you a better experience.

Comment: Unfortunately those changes still don't work.
The only thing I've gotten to work so far is making a timer, like int timer=0;, and in the loop timer++; and if (timer>=100) break;. 
That stops the stall in the beginning completely. But of course that's not usable if I want an infinite game loop or something. 
The program knows it is an infinite loop, and for that reason the stall occurs, it seems to me.
If I change the timer to 1000, instead of 100, there is a small noticeable stall before execution. And if I change it to 10000, there is a very long stall again, similar to infinite loop.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't think of anything else.  I actually did build the program above on my Windows machine as well using Code::Blocks and it is behaving.  FYI, I am using the "gcc" compiler and I built the project as a console project if that helps.  Otherwise, I can't think of anything else to add.  Hope you can sort out a solution.